# Given hash(x) and y, can I verify z = hash(x + y)?

Tags: hash

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve:

- `y` is public, it's a timestamp
- there is A who knows `x` - it's a file
- A can send B some information about the file (a hash?), but not the full file (it's too big)
- A then sends the file `x` to C

The role of B now, is to periodically verify that at given time `y` C still has the file `x`. C could send something like `hash(x, y)` to B, and B (who doesn't have the full `x`) needs a way to verify that C indeed has the full file `x` at time `y`.

---

Here's the original question I've asked (it includes the solution approach I've been trying to take):

Say I only know hash(x) and y.

I receive z that is supposed to be hash(x + y)? Is there any way I can verify that without knowing x?

I'm interested in any mechanism that could make such check possible rather than particular hash and + operations.

Comment: The edit helped clear up the question quite a bit, and I suggest actually changing the order: The actual question should be what you want to achieve - and the construction with hashes is just a possible solution - and it's fine to ask "does this work?". Atm, it seems to be a candidate for the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thanks tylo I wasn't aware of the XY problem. I've updated my question.

Comment: Can B request information from A at any time after the file has been sent to C? If so, B could periodically generate a random seed and ask both A and C to send a hash generated with that seed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The technical term for what you're looking for is "publicly verifiable proof of retrievability". [Here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12719/does-there-exist-a-proof-of-retrievability-scheme-that-is-publicly-verifiable-l) is a question on crypto.SE that discusses existing implementations of PoRs.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit to make this a  stand-alone answer?

Answer (score 6):

After you described the actual problem, here's what you can do without breaking any security assumptions or putting restrictions on file $x$:

1. Solution: Instead of having $C$ calculate $hash(x,y)$, it just $hash(x)$ to $B$. $B$ just needs to check that he got the same hash both from $A$ and $B$. $y$ is public anyway. Or $C$ could also send $y$ along with the hash.
2. Solution: If $C$ can digitally sign messages and $B$ knows the verification key of $C$, then it would be enough if $C$ sends a message $Sign(hash(x) || y)$. B has $hash(x)$ (directly from $A$) and $y$, knows the verification key and can check the signature. $C$ obviously only can sign $hash(x)||y$ only if $C$ actually has either $x$ or $hash(x)$.

---

We got two more conditions from the comments:

- $C$ has to prove to posess $x$ and not just $hash(x)$
- $B$ wants to check periodically

I don't think that's possible at all, if you don't include Alice again in the periodic steps or the process becomes really large (scaling with size of $x$ instead of the hash). Here's the reason why:

- A proof of knowledge of $x$ would be possible, and it would prove freshness because $B$ can always use different random coins. But that would probably scale with $x$.
- In order to prove freshness you need to make the protocol dependent on random choices of $B$, otherwise it doesn't work because $C$ could just replay an old transcript.
- Using hash function (or similar constructions) with length extension properties do not help at all: If $B$ can use the extension technique for checking, then $C$ can use the extension technique to create the new hash.
- $B$ doesn't know $x$. Even if we consider arbitrary oneway functions (with or without trapdoor, keys, etc.) and $B$ only knowing $f(x)$, any homomorphic property (e.g. used in a proofs of knowledge) could be used by both $C$ and $B$.

Comment: "only if C actually has either x or hash(x)"
I should probably have mentioned that in the question:
what I want to verify in B, is that C actually has the whole file `x` at the time `y`, not just a hash of it

Comment: More XY problems, it seems... Checking that $C$ has $x$ and not only $h(x)$ wasn't stated previously. Having $B$ check periodically and that it has to reflect the current state (and not just at one time) was also missing.

Comment: sorry, turns out it's not that easy to ask the question properly

Comment: @gysyky No problem. I just don't think what you want is actually possible.

Comment: I think you're right that it's not possible with all my restrictions. Thank you for the analysis you've done

Comment: @tylo: what do you think about using PDP as outlined in the 3rd and 4th paragraphs of my answer? That's assuming we allows sizable transfer of information from A to B (but still much less than $x$), using a secure protocol; and ignore the new the requirement in this [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44994?noredirect=1#comment102729_44999) that B only holds public information.

Comment: @fgrieu Yes, I think that would work. However, as you already pointed out: it does not work any more when $B$ just has public information. In the PDP scheme the verifier is required to hold some metadata - and that is effectively giving him some information about the file itself.

Answer (score 5):

As to the first part of the [current](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/44994/4) question: it was [previously](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/44994/3) proposed that B receive $\operatorname{hash}(x)$ from A, then check $\operatorname{hash}(x+y)$ computed and sent periodically by C, comparing that against a recomputation made from $\operatorname{hash}(x)$ and $y$, using some property thought in the current question's title and second part.

That technique fails if C is dishonest. Problem is, C can compute $\operatorname{hash}(x)$ and discard $x$ (including while receiving and hashing $x$) and then use the very property used by B for verification. As a more easily solved aside, that technique also fails against an adversary having intercepted $\operatorname{hash}(x)$ sent to B, then impersonating C to B.

The problem is reminiscent of PDP: Provable (or proof of) Data Possession. Formalization of that problem is attributed to Giuseppe Ateniese, Randal Burns, Reza Curtmola, Joseph Herring, Lea Kissner, Zachary Peterson and Dawn Song with [*Provable data possession at untrusted stores*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ff6e/5341fe4ecca1f78ad4c0b834062f56f5b1ef.pdf) (in [proceedings of CCS 2007](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1315318)). A followup reference article by the same authors plus Osama Khan is [*Remote data checking using provable data possession*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1deb/0df1b2075f9570041471b8bd76df501dac86.pdf), in [ACM TISSec 2011](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1952994).

Any PDP method can be used for the question's purpose by securely sending from A to B (with confidentiality and integrity) whatever the data originator of PDP is supposed to keep; but this does *not* match the requirement in this [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44994?noredirect=1#comment102729_44999) that B only holds public information.

---

As tho the original question (it's current second part): depending on the security properties thought for the hash, and the freedom we have about what $+$ is, what's asked is possible, or not.

For a hash with the security objective of being secure in the [Random Oracle Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle) (informally: behaving like a random function), and all except very degenerate $+$, what's asked is clearly not possible, because it is a testable property that a random function would not have.

However, with common hashes like SHA-256, and $+$ taken as concatenation $\|$, something quite similar is possible: with $y$ starting with a certain prefix depending only on the length of $x$ (or $x$ ending with that), we can compute $\operatorname{SHA-256}(x\|y)$ from $\operatorname{SHA-256}(x)$ and $y$. That's the [length-extension property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack) (which breaks SHA-256 in the Random Oracle Model not adapted to allow the length-extension property, but is not against the originally stated security objectives of SHA-256).

Still with $+$ being concatenation, it seems possible to craft a hash without any restriction on the content of $x$ and $y$. However the solutions that I immediately see have some drawbacks, like a lesser security argument, constraints on the length of $x$, or/and reduced efficiency.

Comment: Nice, thanks @fgrieu. I'll definitely take a look at the length-extension property.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want C to be able to prove that they have $x$ at time $y$ (given that we know they had $x$ at some earlier time).

Your idea is that B wants to be able to verify that the value C provides is actually $\mathrm{hash}(x \| y)$.  Further,the idea is that given $\mathrm{hash}(x)$ and $y$, B can calculate $\mathrm{hash}(x \| y)$ and compares with C's value; if they match, all is good.

The problem is that this doesn't provide you the guarantee you want.  We know that at some point C had $x$, so C can easily remember $\mathrm{hash}(x)$ *and repeat exactly the same calculation as B performs*.

It feels like this is the sort of thing you ought to be able to do with some sort of asymmetric cryptography, but I don't know how.

Other concerns: This would be easier if $y$ was a random challenge provide by B. If that's not acceptable for some reason, C needs to derive $y$ by hashing a certificate returned by an time-stamping service.  C will then need to send this certificate to B and B will need to verify it.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. Turns out there's one more thing I forgot to mention in the original question: everything that B knows is public, I'm not sure if random challenge would work in such case.

Comment: They don't actually need to be random - just unpredictable.  So C can't 1.  work at what *y* will be in a year's time; 2. calculate the value; 3. remember it; 4. throw *x* away; 5. send out the saved value at the appropriate time

Comment: A heartily welcome to crypto, Martin. Your reputation precedes you. I'll try and get back to you when I need a Greenland paddle (woodworking reference) ;)

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on your hash function and operator. For example, for Merkle-Dåmgard hash functions (MD5, SHA1, SHA2) and concatenation, it is easy. For SHA3, in general you cannot determine $\mathrm{hash}(x \| y)$ without knowing $x$.

Comment: _"it is easy_" is an oversimplification. We need additional constraints on either $x$ or $y$. See [my answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/44996/555).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mark. As noted in my question, I'm really interested in mechanism how could I implement a system with such possibilities.

To clear up a bit:

- `y` is public, it's a timestamp
- there is A who knows `x` - it's a file
- A tells B `hash(x)` (or any other needed piece of information about `x`, but not the `x` itself  - it's too big)
- A sends `x` to C
- C needs to send confirmation to B "I have `x` at the moment, as a proof here's `hash(x, y)`
- B needs to verify that what it received is indeed a hash of a file and a timestamp